# MFC: Getting Access Violation Error when Using an Object's Member Function in a Worker Thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-c++, mfc

I'm working on migrating an MFC application from Windows XP to Windows 7, and I've come across a somewhat major roadblock to completing this thing.

Take this code segment, for example (m_cDatabase is a wrapper class for the CDatabase object):

```
MyApp* pApp = (MyApp*)AfxGetApp();
pApp->m_cDatabase.CloseDatabase();
```

The code runs in the main thread, but it throws an access violation exception if it runs in a worker thread. The worker thread was created using the Windows threading API (the one with HANDLE, and stuff), but I've seen some code that uses the MFC threading API (the one with Afxbeginthread, etc.). Is it possible that the Windows threading API is throwing it off? Should I try to use the MFC framework, instead?

Comment: Your code has bugs. They will be there regardless of which API you use.

Comment: Yeah, I just tried using the MFC API. Still no dice. Looks like I'm gonna have to find a way to hack around this thing.

Comment: If you need to access MFC objects from another thread, you **must** use `AfxBeginThread` to spawn the worker otherwise MFC's multithreading support will not be correctly initialised. [See here for a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21718917/2065121).

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, objects that are derived from MFC classes (let's call these MFC objects) can only be accessed from the thread that they were created created; this is because many of the MFC objects are thin wrappers to underlying objects (e.g. most of the `CWnd` derived stuff) and internal data is stored in thread-specific maps.

Without knowing about what `m_cDatabase` represents, it's hard to know if it falls into the category of objects described above, but given that you're crashing I'd say that it is.

You have a few options available to you. The two that are likely the easiest are:

1. You can create the `m_cDatabase` in the thread itself and use it. You will need to pass all the arguments necessary to construct it. You will, also, need to do the same thing for any other MFC object instances that your thread uses.
2. You can see if the class that `m_cDatabase` is an instance of offers a way to retrieve an underlying handle that is thread-safe. If so, you can pass the handle to the thread, which can then either access the handle directly, or possibly construct an MFC wrapper around it if the class offers a method like `FromHandle`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Nik! Unfortunately, the class doesn't have a way to pass a thread-safe handle, so I'll probably be going with something like #1.