# how to wait for a variable to be true before continuing in C++ MFC?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc

I have a MFC GUI thread to send/read message to/from hardware and another MFC worker thread to send a few command over to control the hardware. How do I wait for a variable to be true before I continue to send the next command? the variable is set true when it receive an acknowledge message back from the hardware.

```
bool PortRead = false;

void onEventRead() // portread will be set to true from gui thread using callback to main thread
{
   PortRead = true; 
}

void sendCommands()
{
 send (message1); 
 wait for Portread == true;
 portread = false; 
 send (message2); 
 wait for Portread == true;
 portread = false; 
}
```

Comment: As you have a GUI, you must use AfxBeginThread, otherwise, your GUI will freeze. See  https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/cpp/parallel/multithreading-creating-worker-threads?view=msvc-160

Comment: @lan Launching an additional thread is not strictly required to implement asynchronous operations. Windows' I/O system is inherently asynchronous, though client code frequently uses the synchronous utility implementations. *"You must use AfxBeginThread"* is thus not accurate.

Comment: @IInspectable I want just to say that we don't use/create thread in GUI like in console application, and for "asynchronous" you can indeed continue to think in monothread on your I5, I7, ... CPU, nothing prenvents it

Comment: @lan Since the OS provides only a single way to create a thread, we create threads in a GUI application **exactly the same way** we create a thread in a console application. Besides, I never implied to write a single-threaded application. It's just that *we*, as developers, don't need to launch an *additional* thread to get asynchronous I/O operations.

Comment: @IInspectable it is not what is suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21718674/difference-between-afxbeginthread-and-createthread

Comment: @lan You fail to understand how frameworks and runtime environments are layered on top of the OS. **All** functions listed in the referenced Q&A will eventually call into the OS to create a thread. The function that ultimately creates a thread is [CreateRemoteThread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createremotethread). That's the *only* function that creates threads. Regardless, none of that makes your statement that *"you must use AfxBeginThread"* accurate. It's wrong, and I have done my best to explain why.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by either [polling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polling_(computer_science)) or an interruption (or callback).
if you want to poll, (also called busy waiting), something like this is enough:

```
// Send signal to hardware
while (!variable) {} // Waits here until variable is true
// Proceed with program
```

Interruptions are a little bit trickier, specially because you did not provide mode details about how you interface with that hardware, or if it has an API or library of some sorts. If you have control over the other thread, you could use `std::condition_variable::wait`, or even a signal/slot scheme using Qt and callbacks.

Based on your code, however, this may work:

```
std::condition_variable cv;
std::mutex cv_m;

void onEventRead()
{
   cv.notify_all();
}

void sendCommands()
{
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(cv_m);
  send (message1); 
  cv.wait(lk); 
  send (message2); 
  cv.wait(lk); 
}
```

For the full example of how to use `std::condition_variable`, see here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait

Comment: Note that either solution will freeze the UI when called from a message handler.

Comment: It is a very bad solution because you have a looping mechanism : While (!variable) wich will use CPU to do nothing ...

Comment: @Landstalker this is not a "bad" solution. It is in fact CPU-heavy (which may be a downside), but it has its benefits: speed. I believe this is how spin-wait is implemented.

Comment: hi thanks!  this is working . how to set a timeout ? in case message is sent but no feedback?

Comment: @Dong Instead of `wait` you can use `wait_for` and set a timeout. See this for more information: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait_for

Comment: @Dong If you instead are using the busy wait method, you need to check for the time elapsed inside the `while` loop.

Comment: i am using conditional variable. thanks !